# Null Safety App not runnable on Flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I've a Flutter app, that was running properly on Flutter 3.0, but after migrating to Null Safety, I receive this while trying to run:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\apps\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\apps\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: this mesage says nothing about the failure

Answer (score -1):

Go to pubspec.yaml file, try doing Packages get | Pub get, and then build the project again.